# Generator function not updating a local variable

Tags: python, generator

I'm working on a problem that I got from a friend, in this problem I need to generate the time in the following format: 00:00:00, 00:00:01, 00:00:02 etc... But to follow the instructions of this problem correctly I need to use generator functions to accomplish that result.
So first of all I need to create three generator functions that generate numbers between 0-59 for secs and mins and 0-23 for hrs.
so I tried to do it, and I think that I did everything correctly but I encountered a problem, let's say that we're talking about the gen_func that generates hours for now (I will call it gen_hr), when I try to use the yield command it works, but it only prints to the screen the number **0** which should be only the beggining of what I really want, I'm trying to update the local variable (it's local to the gen_hr generator function), but it's not updating, everytime I try to print the next produced value it prints **0**.
**HERE'S THE CODE:**

```
def gen_hours():
    hr = 0

    while hr < 24:
        if hr < 10:
            yield f"0{hr}"
            hr += 1
        else:
            yield hr
            hr += 1
```

**AND HERE'S THE OUTPUT:**

```
for i in range(10):
    print(next(gen_hours()))

>>> 00
>>> 00
>>> 00
>>> 00
>>> 00
>>> 00
>>> 00
>>> 00
>>> 00
>>> 00
```

**HERE IS THE OUTPUT THAT I WAS EXPECTING:**

```
>>> 01
>>> 02
>>> 03
>>> 04
>>> 05
>>> 06
>>> 07
>>> 08
>>> 09
>>> 10
```

It would be wonderful if you help me understand what's wrong with my code.

Comment: You are looping over a `range` object. Inside the body of that loop, you do `print(next(gen_hours()))` which **creates a new generator object** and calls `next` on it. The first item in the generator is always `"00"`, hence you get `"00"` 10 times. That generator that you create is discarded once the `next` returns.

Comment: What you probably *meant* to do is just `for hour in gen_hours(): print(hour)`

Comment: 1) Why are you expecting `01` if you yield zero first? 2) You know you can use `{:02d}` for padding? 3) Why not use `strftime`?

Comment: @OneCricketeer For '1' I'm still new to generators, that's why I posted the question...
'2': I didn't want to use str formating
'3': The problem that I'm doing requires me to do it my self using generator funcs and expressions...
Thanks for commenting though!

Comment: Was a fine question, you only would have gotten `01` ten times instead, if you incremented first. You can still use a random integer generator with time/timedelta objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should first create a generator and then call `next` on it:

```
gen = gen_hours()
for i in range(10):
    print(next(gen))
```

a different way to achieve just that using [`islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) is:

```
from itertools import islice

for h in islice(gen_hours(), 10):
    print(h)
```

you code creates a fresh generator in each iteration of the loop and calls `next` to always get the first element.